# Converting a string to a wav file in python

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I'm new to Python, and to programming in general, so please don't take it too hard on me

I am currently trying to figure out how to write a new wav file using a string (which was derived from another wave file's data)

I performed a fourier transform on that file's data, so now I'm trying to get the values from the Fourier transform written into a new wav file.

I can only use numpy and the included Python library, not scipy

According to the documentation, I have to use wave_write(), but I have no idea what the code is supposed to look like for this function.

I think I'm supposed to do something pertaining to

```
wave_write.writeframesraw(data)
```

Then again, not totally sure of what to do. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not scipy? You have [scipy.io.wavfile.write](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) that does have limitations but which is otherwise straightforward to use once you have a Numpy array.

Comment: My [tutorial on the wave module](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb) might help?

Answer (score 0):

Two functions in NumPy can help you with this: `astype` and `tostring`.

If you have an array of sound samples, say `X` then you can convert it to the right format using `astype`. This will depend on what data type is used in the wav file, and the library you are using to save it. But let us for this example say you want to store it as 16 bit integer. You'll need to scale X according to the data type selected - so in this case the range will be -32768 to 32767 for a signed 16 bit int. If you sample goes from -1.0 to 1.0 then you can simply multiply with 32767.

The next part is simply to convert it to a string using `tostring`, it could look something the following:

```
scaled = X * 32767
scaled.astype('<i2').tostring()
```

You can find the documentation for the functions here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html